# can OFBiz be configured to work as a single monolithic webapp?

Tags: deployment, module, package, war, ofbiz

OFBiz by default works as a collections of small webapps each with its own front controller.  OFBiz webapps typically depend on a lot of common modules.  Typically, modules under specialpurpose or hot-deploy would end up depending on pretty much all of the modules under **framework** and **applications**...  with the embedded container, all libraries go into the catalina shared library class loader but if ofbiz needs to be deployed in a different container, there is simply no easy way.  the only options i believe are

1. package ofbiz as an EAR with a **EAR/lib** or **EAR/APP-INF/lib** so that all webapps have access to a common set of EAR level classpath resources.. typically each modules's **config**, **lib** and the all important **ofbiz-$module.jar**
2. each webapp packages each of the required jars into its own **WEB-INF/lib**.. too much duplication and also increases the filesystem footprint in a sense
3. use the application system classpath in lieu of catalina shared.lib folder - which means the JVM has to be dedicated to ofbiz as its jars would otherwise interfere with other sibling deployments and potentially even with the container itself, typically things such as XML, XSL, STAX apis etc..

given that ofbiz load most of the resources using the filesystem (**ofbiz.home** + **component://**) resulution.  What the webapp really needs access to in a convential servlet context kind of way is the

- controller.xml
- classpath resources - across the various ofbiz-$module.jar in shared.lib.  typically, each modules's **config**, **lib** and the all important **ofbiz-$module.jar**
- imported (component://) webapp resources like other controller.xml for various modules.  most importantly the **framework/common/webcommon/WEB-INF/controller.xml** that provides the boiler plate security implementation like checkLogin and autoLogin....

I was wondering if we could somehow package multiple webapps into a single monolithic webapp using front controller namespacing so that the war maps to a single root content like say **/** (**ROOT** on tomcat) and **/content**, **/webtools**, **/catalog**, **/ecommerce** etc. are mere URL namespaces/subcontexts rather than separate webapps.  **framework/common/webcommon/WEB-INF/controller.xml** could become the root controller for / (ROOT in tomcat) and provide checkLogin, autoLogin etc to all webapps without each controller having to import that controller.xml

This would allow us to simply the deployment model when we would want to move to other containers like say weblogic, jboss et al where we would be better of building a single webapp with all of its dependencies neatly packaged into its **WEB-INF/lib** such that it could coexist with other deployments in the same container without interfering with their dependencices and their versions...

I believe struts had this kind of modular namespacing where there could be a root level struts.xml (our case controller.xml) and each module would be a folder with its own module/struts.xml or module/struts-module.xml etc...

i personally feel this would be helpful.. i have not thought enough about the downsides.  there could be many?  i honestly don't know.  I have not given enough thought to themes either.. developers clearly would not like to see any change in the way code is laid out or organized.. so with some minor? :) changes in the core MVC code in the framework, we could potentially support this kind of deployment using a simple ant build script that stages candidate webapps into a merged monolithic webapp...

i was hoping to see a debate on the merits of this idea...  i would even be willing to invest some time into making this work if i get some direction and inputs..

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using chef to deploy Ofbiz instead?

I wrote the following cookbook to demonstrate how it could work:

- https://github.com/myspotontheweb/chef-ofbiz

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult part of how Apache OFBiz is architected. Using EAR files works okay, but shared classpath resources in an EAR file are app-server specific, and you have to deploy in a container that supports EAR files which limits choices.

One of the limitations is the flat namespace for requests in the controller.xml files, and what you describe would be the best way to handle that (use a different ControlServlet mount point for each OFBiz component app). Doing so may require some code changes for the URL writing (the @ofbizUrl FTL tag and the underlying code used elsewhere). It would also require a bit of work to write an ant target or something to build the WAR file, pulling in all the webapps from the various components (or just those desired), writing a combined web.xml file, etc, etc.

This is a recognized issue with OFBiz, and isn't a problem for most deployments, but does make it more difficult to scale down or host along with other applications. You can add other webapps through OFBiz components to host them on the embedded servlet container, but I don't imagine that is what you are looking for.

One of the issues with making this and many similar changes in OFBiz is the large code base, large user base, and the somewhat large committer group with diverse opinions on things like this. For these and other reasons a lot of the ideas for improving OFBiz can't be easily realized there, and that is why I started the Moqui Framework project in 2010.

Moqui deploys with a single WAR file, and can have an external or embedded runtime directory to make it easy to deploy on WAR hosting services such as AWS ElasticBeanstalk, as well as dropping in to servlet containers such as Apache Tomcat. The WAR file is also an executable JAR file using an embedded Winstone servlet container for easier development and automated testing. There are details about running and deploying Moqui here:

http://www.moqui.org/framework/docs/RunDeploy.html

BTW, this is one of hundreds of ideas for improvements to OFBiz that made it into Moqui Framework and the separate project with data model and services (Mantle Business Artifacts). There is general information about it here:

http://www.moqui.org/

Comment: thanks for your views David.  i had a suspicion that what i was asking for a non-trivial change.  You can never underestimate the genius of the community, so was trying my luck :) I have been following your moqui project and look forward to seeing how it develops and finds wider acceptance.  Would you call this production ready as of today?

Comment: Yes, Moqui is currently production ready (has been for a while, though especially since late 2012). You are correct though that it is still not used widely and the more comprehensive business artifacts built on it are much more recent, first release only a few months ago.